Finding 6 unknowns x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3 in terms of x1,y1 using Solve function
Dear Mathematica Users,
I have a question about Solve function in Mathematica which runs so much time and does not give anything. If you try the below code, you will see what I mean. If there is no answer, it must give {} but it still does not give anything. I have 9 equations and 6 unknowns. I want  these 6 unknowns to be determined by the other known values which are x1,y1. What do you suggest me to get a result? Thanks, Ahmet.
Solve[(y1/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2]*z2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2] - x3/Sqrt[
 x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] == 0) &&
((-1*x1)/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2]*z2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2] - y3/Sqrt[
x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] == 0) &&
(x1/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2]*y2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2] - 
y1/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2]*x2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2] - z3/Sqrt[
x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] == 0) &&
(y2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2]*z3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] - 
z2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2]*y3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] - x1/Sqrt[
x1^2 + y1^2] == 0) &&
(z2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2]*x3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] - 
x2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2]*z3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] - y1/Sqrt[
x1^2 + y1^2] == 0) &&
(x2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2]*y3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] - 
y2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2]*x3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2] == 0) &&
((-1*z3)/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2]*y1/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2] - x2/Sqrt[
x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2] == 0) &&
(z3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2]*x1/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2] - y2/Sqrt[
x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2] == 0) && (x3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2]*y1/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2] - y3/Sqrt[x3^2 + y3^2 + z3^2]*x1/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2] - z2/Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2] == 0),
{x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3}]


You can use GroebnerBasis and then Solve. I am getting these results: {{x2 -> -((y1^2 z2 z3)/(x3 (x1^2 + y1^2))),    y2 -> (x1 y1 z2 z3)/(x3 (x1^2 + y1^2)),    y3 -> -((x1 x3)/y1)}, {y2 -> -((x1 x2)/y1), z2 -> 0, x3 -> 0,    y3 -> 0}}

@yarchik I define a vector lies on xy plane as x1 i + y1 j + 0 k  in which x1 and y1 are preassumed in the analysis and then I want to find another two vectors (x2 i+ y2 j, z2 k ) and (x3 i + y3 j+ z3 k) which must be orthogonal to each other and also to orthogonal to the preassumed first vector. All these equations come from the cross products of these three vectors which bring three equations for each of the three cross products totally nine equations.

@yarchik: Unfortunately, substituting it tn the system under consideration, one does not obtain True even after the simplification., but a complicated system. I have doubts concerning the usage of GroebnerBasis to a non-polynomial system

@user64494 I am getting True when substituting the solutions into the original equations, applying FullSimplifyand assuming all variables to be positive. I did not investigate this further, therefore, I have not posted it as a solution, just as an idea.

@yarchik:  I have just executed these substitutions in the system from the question under consideration on a fresh kernel in 14.1 on Windows with the same result : not True, but complicated systems. The executed nb file on demand. I repeat that Groebner basis works only for polynomial systems ( see the documentation).

@The down-voters: It is unfair to down vote without any explaining comment.

You wrote "I define a vector lies on xy plane as x1 i + y1 j + 0 k in which x1 and y1 are preassumed in the analysis and then I want to find another two vectors (x2 i+ y2 j, z2 k ) and (x3 i + y3 j+ z3 k) which must be orthogonal to each other and also to orthogonal to the preassumed first vector " in your comment to your question. This can be done by using scalar products (see the documentation for info), not vector products, as follows.
Solve[{x2, y2, z2} . {x1, y1, 0} == 0 && {x3, y3, z3} . {x1, y1, 0} ==
 0 && {x3, y3, z3} . {x2, y2, z2} == 0, {x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3}, 
  Reals] // FullSimplify


{{x2 -> ConditionalExpression[(x1 y1 z2 z3)/(x1^2 y3 + y1^2 y3),  y3 != 0],  y2 -> ConditionalExpression[-((z2 z3)/(y3 + (y1^2 y3)/x1^2)),  y3 != 0],  x3 -> ConditionalExpression[-((y1 y3)/x1), y3 != 0]}, {x2 -> -(( y1 y2)/x1), x3 -> 0, y3 -> 0,  z3 -> 0}, {x2 -> ConditionalExpression[-((y1 y2)/x1), z3 != 0],  z2 -> ConditionalExpression[0, z3 != 0],  x3 -> ConditionalExpression[0, z3 != 0],  y3 -> ConditionalExpression[0, z3 != 0]}}

Addition. If you want the vector product of {x1,x2,0} and {x2,y2,z2} equals {x3,y3,z3}}  and so on, then
Solve[Cross[{x1,y1,0},{x2,y2,z2}]=={x3,y3,z3}&&Cross[{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3}]=={x1,y1,0}&&Cross[{x3,y3,z3},{x1,y1,0}]=={x2,y2,z2},{x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3}]

results in {}. and this means there is no generic solution even over the complexes (Of course, the solution can exist for some concrete values of x1 and y1, for example, x1==1 and y1==0.).

Solve[Cross[{x1, y1, 0}, {x2, y2, z2}] == {x3, y3, z3} &&    Cross[{x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}] == {x1, y1, 0} &&    Cross[{x3, y3, z3}, {x1, y1, 0}] == {x2, y2, z2}, {x2, y2, z2, x3,    y3, z3}, Assumptions -> x1^2 + y1^2 == 1] results in {x2 -> y1 Sqrt[1 - z2^2], y2 -> -x1 Sqrt[1 - z2^2], x3 -> y1 z2,    y3 -> -x1 z2, z3 -> -Sqrt[1 - z2^2]}, {x2 -> -y1 Sqrt[1 - z2^2],    y2 -> x1 Sqrt[1 - z2^2], x3 -> y1 z2, y3 -> -x1 z2,    z3 -> Sqrt[1 - z2^2]}} and a warning "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables".

Thank you for your effort. Your solution is nearly what I want, however, I don't want an assumption x1^2+y1^2=1 since it can be different from 1 by the selection of x1 and y1. Additionally, I don't want the unknowns to be obtained in terms of other unknowns, i.e, x2=y1Sqrt[1-z2^2]. I want the unknowns (x2,y2,z2 and x3,y3,z3) to be obtained in terms of x1 and y1 which are the known values that will be given by the user.

Why don't you verify your solutions by substituting them in the original equations?

I think you don't understand my answer written above yarchik. Please first read my answer. Surely, I try your solutions in my own Mathematica. However, here,  the problem is there is an assumption which is not correct for the physical meaning and also the unknowns need to be found in terms of the knowns not unknowns. I think @user64494 understand what I mean.

The downvoters: What is incorrect in my answer. It is unfair to down vote without any explaining comment.

@yarchik: You wrote "Why don't you verify your solutions by substituting them in the original equations?". I don't solve the system from the question at all.  I answer "I define a vector lies on xy plane as x1 i + y1 j + 0 k in which x1 and y1 are preassumed in the analysis and then I want to find another two vectors (x2 i+ y2 j, z2 k ) and (x3 i + y3 j+ z3 k) which must be orthogonal to each other and also to orthogonal to the preassumed first vector ".

After reading your comment about the origin of these equations, I realised that there is an easy way to construct an orthogonal family of vectors starting from the given one {x1,y1,0}. Let us denote
v[1] = {x1, y1, 0};
v[2] = {0, 0, t};
v[3] = Cross[v[1], v[2]] * s;

It is easy to verify that this set of vectors already satisfies the desired properties:
Simplify[(eqs /. Join[Thread[{x2, y2, z2} -> v[2]], Thread[{x3, y3, z3} -> v[3]]]), Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals] && s>0]
(* {True} *)

Here eqs is the original list of equations. However, this is not the most general solution as one can rotate vectors v[2] and v[3] around the axis given by v[1]:
k = ComplexExpand[Normalize[v[1]]]
u[1]=v[1];
u[2]=v[2]Cos[θ]+Cross[k,v[2]]Sin[θ]+k(k.v[2])(1-Cos[θ]);
u[3]=v[3]Cos[θ]+Cross[k,v[3]]Sin[θ]+k(k.v[3])(1-Cos[θ]);

Here, the rotation is parametrised by the angle $\theta$, and the Rodrigues` rotation formula is used.  Now we can verify the more general solution:
Simplify[(eqs /. Join[Thread[{x2, y2, z2} -> u[2]], Thread[{x3, y3, z3} -> u[3]]]), Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals] && s>0]
(* {True} *)

Additionally we can verify the dot products:
Table[v[i] . v[j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}] // MatrixForm
FullSimplify[Table[u[i] . u[j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]] // MatrixForm

The answer in both cases is a diagonal matrix as expected for orthogonal family of vectors.

All that is done by hand with help of Mathematica. It remains unclear whether the complete general family of such vectors is found by you.

In fact, you don't find the comlete description of such vectors: think of v[2] = {0, 0, -2}.

It is not a good practice to change the answer (v[2] = {0, 0, t}; instead of v[2] = {0, 0, 1};), not describing the edit. I also  repeat it remains unclear from your edited answer whether the complete general family of such vectors is found by you.

@user64494 Yes, vectors v[2] and v[3] can be scaled. Thanks for pointing out.

yarchik: Sorry, this is  not any proof. Regard.

The complete description of such vectors is done by Reduce[{x2, y2, z2} . {x1, y1, 0} == 0 && {x3, y3, z3} . {x1, y1, 0} ==      0 && {x3, y3, z3} . {x2, y2, z2} == 0, {x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3},    Reals] // FullSimplify. In my answer I used Solve to produce a generic solution for simplicity.

@yarchik  Thank you for your efforts. You have defined three vectors v[1], v[2] and v[3] and you specify v[2] and v[3] by inserting parameters t and s, respectively. Later, you have inserted these vectors into my equation list and they verify the equations. However,  I want to insert only v[1]'s parameters x1 and y1 and later to find the other vectors components in terms of x1 and y1 using orthogonality conditions which are u1 x u2 = u3; u2xu3=u1; u3xu1=u2 and u1.u2=0; u2.u3=0; u3.u1=0. I want to set a family of orthogonal unit vectors for directions 2 and 3 in terms of direction1's components

@KazimAhmetHasim There is no unique solution in terms of x1 and y1. The solutions are parametrised in terms of constants $t$, $s$ and $\theta$. In particular, the vectors can be shorter or longer, and they will still be orthogonal. That is why v[2] and v[3] are parametrised by their length, i.e., t and s. Furthermore, these vectors can be rotated by an arbitrary angle $\theta$ along the original vector, and they will still be orthogonal.

@KazimAhmetHasim From your profile, it seems you tend not to accept solutions to your posts. This is not fair to people who spend their time to help you. But what is even more important, such posts are of no use for future visitors, because they will not understand whether proposed solutions are good or not. It is a good style here to upvote and accept the posts that you like, or downvote explaining why post that you do not like. Furthermore, this forum is specifically for Mathematica questions. General mathematical questions should be directed to your lecturer/supervisor or different forums.

@yarchik why are you answering like this? You have tried, thank you but your answer is just trying to verify the equations I have already given and you can't get a solution for the unknowns in terms of x1 and y1. Also, please be more kind to people!

@KazimAhmetHasim "you can't get a solution for the unknowns in terms of x1 and y1" this is absolutely not true. Take u[2] and u[3], put in any real number for $t$, $\theta$ and any positive number for $s$ and you will get a perfect solution. You can take another combination of $t$, $s$ and $\theta$ and you will get another valid solution. What is exactly your problem?

@yarchik you have defined as the vectors like this: v[1] = {x1, y1, 0};v[2] = {0, 0, t};v[3] = Cross[v[1], v[2]]*s; when I vector product Cross[v[2], v[3]], the solution vector should be equal to v1, isn't it correct ? However, I get the solution different from v[1] and only satisfied with s=t=1.

@yarchik then we find another relation that st^2=1 to satisfy v[1] ={x1,y1,0} isn't it.
